# How to create Docker run-time argument to copy a host file at runtime into the container?

Tags: docker

I'm trying to create a Docker image for Squid3 which when run will accept a command-line parameter representing the file on the host to copy over `/etc/squid/squid.conf` *within* the container. I don't think this is possible, because the argument would be processed by the container itself and therefore have no access to the host. However, I thought I'd ask in case there's some magic I haven't found yet.

In the absence of this, I'd just use the `kotaimen/squid3` image (https://github.com/Kotaimen/docker-squid3) which has you mount a volume to map to `/etc/squid`.

Anyway, I think it'd be really nice to be able to do something like so:

```sh
docker pull squid3
docker run squid3 ~/squid.conf
```

I'm still early in the process of creating this so any suggestions are welcome. I'm looking at the Squid3 images on DockerHub for reference.

Comment: You don't need a custom image; the `docker run` command on the GitHub page you link to can do it.  Is there a specific problem you're running into?

Comment: It's done with specisl parameters now. 
 No special hacks like before.  https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/configure-dns/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you already understood all arguments passed on the command line are processed by the program within the container - which of course has no direct access to the host filesystem.

In order to place a file from the host filesystem into the container I only see 2 reasonable ways (and 1 unreasonable):

1. Volume-mount the respective file - similar to the `kotaimen/squid3` image:

   - no need for a custom image
   - file is mounted/changed at run-time

```sh
docker run -v ~/squid.conf:/etc/squid/squid.conf:ro squid3
```

2. Create your own image which includes your custom config into the base image:

   - config is included in the image
   - can only be changed at build-time

```
# Dockerfile
FROM squid3
COPY squid.conf /etc/squid/squid.conf
```

3. The hacky way: use a custom script as entrypoint which ready the config from stdin. Then you can pass the file at start-up:

```sh
docker run --entrypoint 'sh -c "cat > /etc/squid/squid.conf; ./entrypoint.sh"' squid3 < ~/squid.conf
```

But this has some serious drawbacks:

- you need to write a custom entrypoint and include it in a custom image **or** use a hacky `--entrypoint` one the command line each time (see above)
- the container can't use stdin for anything else like especially interactive input anymore
- the entrypoint is run on every container re-/start even if no stdin is connected then, i.e. this would result in an empty config after the container restart:

```sh
docker run --name squid3 --entrypoint 'sh -c "cat > /etc/squid/squid.conf; ./entrypoint.sh"' squid3 < ~/squid.conf
docker restart squid3
```

Comment: Awesome, see I didn't realize `-v` could map individual files rather than just directories. That's exactly what I needed